# Is it possible to combine two pre-existing databases into one front-end?

Tags: python, sql, database, frontend, backend

I am new at working with databases, and I have been given the task to combine data from two large databases as part of an internship program (heavily focused on the learning experience, but not many people at the job are familiar with databases). The options are either to create a new table or database, or make a front-end that pulls data from both databases. Is it possible to just make a front-end for this? There is an issue of storage if a new database has to be created.

I'm still on the stage where I'm trying to figure out exactly how I'm going to go about doing this, and how to access the data in the first place. I have the table data for the two databases that are already in existence and I know what items need to be pulled from both. The end goal is a website where the user can input one of the values and output the all the information about that item. One of the databases is an Oracle database in SQL and the other is a Cisco Prime database. I am planning to work in Python if possible. Any guidance on this would be very helpful!

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Under the hood it's just sql statements that are passed through a connection to each database. You decide what that SQL is which server/connection to send it to and how you handle the result sets that are returned. Since your question is light on details there's not much more to say.

Comment: The main issue I see with keeping 2 separate databases is you can't directly do queries that use tables from both, that is JOINs.  You have to make separate queries then simulate the JOINs using python code.  That can be horribly inefficient if you need to fetch 10,000 rows to find the 1 you care about.

Comment: But if you do decide to go that way, Python's `pandas` module will be helpful. You can load data from a SQL query into a Pandas dataframe, and it implements all the relational operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly OK to access both data sources from a single frontend.

Having said that, it might be a problem if you need to combine data from both datasources in large quantities. Because you might have to reimplement some relational database functions such as join, sort, group by.

Python is perfectly OK to connect to Oracle DataSources. Not so sure about Cisco Prime (which is an unusual database).

I would recommend using Linux or Mac (not Windows) if you are new to Python, since both platforms are more python friendly than Windows.

Comment: As I just mentioned in a comment, you can use `pandas` to implement the relational functions.

Comment: So would you say my best bet would be to create the front end first?

Comment: In my opinion, step 1 should be an analysis of goals and requirements, not to start coding.  Is the inefficiency of separate queries and running `pandas` code acceptable if it lets you use only the existing database servers?  Or will that cause performance issues that matter?  Unless this is 100% learning experience and all you want to learn is creating the front end, not whether it is the correct solution.